# Using Fat Secret Api in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, oauth

I would like to use the [Fat Secret API](http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/) in a Rails 3 application to get nutrition data for an item. I don't need to authenticate any users. I have an development account, with a key and shared secret. However, I don't really understand the [OAuth1 authentication](http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth). How would I go about accomplishing this? I tried using the 'passport' gem, but got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is an example of authentication with the API I can help you with that. This API is only OAuth1 so we can use the standard `oauth` gem to reduce the boilerplate code that we need to write.

Using the OAuth gem we want to create a consumer and then make a request to the API like so:

```
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("key", "secret", :site => "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api")
@consumer.request(:post, '', token = nil, {:method => "recipe_types.get"})
```

I wish I could test this but the API signup wont let me test without a URL.

Comment: This Didn't work, it returned 'Missing required oauth parameter: oauth_signature_method'. However, the code at http://groups.google.com/group/fatsecret-platform-api/browse_thread/thread/45b3e8efa412c660/c45159103b1dcd94?lnk=gst&q=rails#c45159103b1dcd94 worked. I would love a more concise version, though. Thanks for helping.